# Redirect ghostscript Output

Tags: pdf, for-loop, encryption, cmd, ghostscript

I use the following command (in a Windows cmd) to decrypt pdf files stored under the directory C:\Users\David\Desktop\BS1999\ and write the output into the same folder using ghostscript:

`FOR %x IN (C:\Users\David\Desktop\BS1999\*.pdf) DO gswin64c -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%x_converted.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f %x`

So in short I have

```
For %x IN (*.pdf) DO my-ghostscript-function %x
```

What modifications do I have to make to redirect the output ("name-of-file"_converted.pdf) to another file path (for example C:\Users\David\Desktop\test)?

Thanks in advance!

Best, David

Comment: `-sOutputFile=C:\Users\David\Desktop\test\%~nx_converted.pdf`. Read `for /?` and/or [Parameter Extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html). Use `for ... do ECHO gswin64c ...` until debugged.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt and precise reply! This solved my problem. Besides many thanks for further reference.